linearly independence of sine functions
I want to check inductively that the vectors $f_n :\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, f_n(x)=\sin(2^{-n}x)$ in the vector space $\hom(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ are linearly independent.
I do not succeed in the inductive step.
I have a sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \lambda_k\cdot f_k =0$. This means that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have
$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\lambda_k\cdot f_k(x)=0$.
I now want that $\sin(2^{-n-1}x)$ vanishes for some specific $x$ where the other $f_i$ do not vanish. Then I can use the inductive hypothesus and conclude that all $\lambda_k =0$ for $1\leq k\leq n$ concluding that $\lambda_{n+1}=0$ also holds.
Which $x$ do I take? $x=2^{n+1}\pi$ does not work as every $f_i$ vanishes at that point. Is there some other senseable choice?
Thank you.

Let $x=2^{n}\pi$. Notice that
$$f_{k}(x)=\sin{(2^{-k}x)}=\sin{(2^{n-k}\pi)}=0,\qquad \forall 1\leq k\leq n$$
But $$f_{n+1}(x)=\sin{(2^{n-(n+1)}\pi)}=\sin{(\pi/2)}=1.$$
Therefore, the identity
$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\lambda_{k} \sin{(2^{-k} x)}=\lambda_{n+1}\sin{(2^{-(n+1)}x)}=0$
implies that $\lambda_{n+1}=0$. Then you have $\lambda_{k}=0$ for all $1\leq k\leq n$ by the induction hypothsis.

OMG. I am so stupid.

If $\{f_1,\cdots,f_n\}$ is linearly dependent, let $g_1(x)=f_1(2^nx),\dots,g_n(x)=f_n(2^nx)$; then $\{g_1,\cdots,g_n\}$ is also linearly dependent. This contradicts this  question .
